# Set static assets as cacheable in Kentico Xperience 13 .NET Core site

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, kentico

I'm trying to use the following code in a .NET Core site running Kentico Xperience 13.

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    OnPrepareResponse = context =>
    {
        context.Context.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] = staticFileCacheHeaderValue;
    },
    HttpsCompression = HttpsCompressionMode.Compress
});
```

This works, in that my static files under wwwroot get their cache-control header (& gzip compression) set.

However, with this code in place, the page builder and form builder scripts and styles no longer load, giving a 404. E.g., in form builder it's supposed to load this file: /Kentico/Scripts/builders/builder.css. Anything which begins /Kentico or /_content suddenly 404s.

This happens whatever I pass as the StaticFileOptions - even a simple `new StaticFileOptions()`.

I've tried calling `app.UseKentico()` both before and after, and this doesn't make a difference. If I call `app.UseStaticFiles()` as well as the above, there are no Kentico errors, but the wwwroot files don't get a cache header applied (nor are they compressed).

I'm not very familiar with .NET Core, so I'm not sure if I'm missing something on that side of things, or whether Kentico is just not playing nicely yet. Any help is, of course, great appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is necessary to set cache-control in the given middleware:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions

{

    OnPrepareResponse = ctx => ctx.Context.Response.Headers.Append(HeaderNames.CacheControl, $"public, max-age={60 * 60 * 24 * 365}"),

    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Environment.ContentRootPath, @"Content")),

    RequestPath = new PathString("/Content")

});
```

Or if I want to set it for the default  *app.UseStaticFiles()*, it is necessary to setup it in
*ConfigureServicesmethod* in *Startup.cs* via *services.Configure* :

```
services.Configure<StaticFileOptions>(options =>
{
    options.OnPrepareResponse = ctx => ctx.Context.Response.Headers.Append(HeaderNames.CacheControl, $"public, max-age={60 * 60 * 24 * 365}");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The services method seems to have worked! The first method you mention didn't work. Presumably the idea is that you are overriding a particular folder? Since everything I want to cache is in wwwroot, I replaced Environment.ContentRootPath with Environment.WebRootPath and "Content" with "fonts" (just to try it out) but this doesn't cache anything. Could you explain the difference between the two approaches please?

Comment: Aah the Kentico docs do in fact say this here: https://docs.xperience.io/developing-websites/developing-xperience-applications-using-asp-net-core/starting-with-asp-net-core-development#StartingwithASP.NETCoredevelopment-Configuringapplicationstartup

Comment: yeah, the first part was related to when you want to use custom folder for static files. I added it there just for reference but forgot to mention it. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: This should be added to the docs @jurajo.  I wanted to cache my wwwroot/bundles directory for 365 days and thought by doing what I did would work, but it caused none of the <domain>/kentico/js... files to be published using DevOps.  Your first solution was the key to target my wwwroot/bundles directory AND include the `app.UseStaticFiles();` above it.